# Help sending serial command to Roomba

Tags: mobile-robot, raspberry-pi, serial, irobot-create, roomba

I have a Raspberry Pi hooked up to a Roomba 560's serial port. While going over [the spec](http://www.irobot.com/images/consumer/hacker/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf), I noticed movement controls weren't as simple as I expected. I can't send bytes larger than 255, but, according to the spec, to go straight I have to send 8000. How does this work?

EDIT: My solution was the following three functions:

```
import serial
import time

def start():
    #Open serial connection
    global ser
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
    # this is the defualt Roomba baud rate
    # Start SCI - puts into safe mode
    ser.write(chr(128))
    # Enable the safe mode
    ser.write(chr(131))
    # this is required or the command may fail
    time.sleep(1)

# This makes the serial command fit the big-endian notation
def make4(num):
    num = num[2:]
    z2a = 4-len(num)
    for q in range(z2a):
        num = '0' + num
    return '\\x'+num

def move(vel, rad):
    # Init move command
    ser.write(chr(137))

    # velocity
    vhex = hex(vel)
    vhex = make4(vhex)

    #radius
    vrad = hex(rad)
    vrad = make4(vrad)

    # send to roomba
    ser.write(vhex)
    ser.write(vrad)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec says hex 8000 as in hexadecimal (which I usually write in C/Python notation as `0x8000`). Each byte is exactly two hexadecimal digits. So you can break `0x8000` into `0x80` and `0x00` and send them separately, which correspond to decimal numbers `128` and `0`.

You also have to know which to send first (referred as little-endian vs big-endian). The spec says [radius high byte] [radius low byte], so high byte comes first (big-endian).

Therefore send the sequence `[128, 0]` in order to transmit hex 8000.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make some nice functions using Python's hex() function so I can put in easily-understandable numbers.